# jquery dropdown show hide tr

Tags: jquery

How do implement the jquery if I want when selected 1 the table will only show tr 1 and when I selected 2 it will show tr 2 and etc?

```
<select name="select_main_table">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Show line 1</option>
<option value="2" >Show line 2</option>
<option value="3" >Show line 3</option>
</select>

<table id="main_table">
 <tr id="show1"><td>line 1</td><td<line 1/td></tr>
 <tr id="show2"><td>line 2</td><td<line 2/td></tr>
 <tr id="show3"><td>line 2</td><td<line 2/td></tr> 
</table>
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a little something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="select_main_table"]').change(function() {
      $("#main_table tr").show().slice(this.value).hide();
   }).change();
});
```

​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kms8k/

**EDIT:** I think my original answer was based on a misunderstanding of your requirement - I thought you meant that selecting "2" meant "show the first two lines". To show only the specified line do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="select_main_table"]').change(function() {
      $("#main_table tr").hide().eq(this.value-1).show();
      // OR
      $("#show" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
   }).change();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kms8k/1/

Notice that you can make it work without using the `id` attribute of the tr elements, should you wish to simplify your html by not including that attribute at all...

All of the jQuery methods I've used are [well documented](http://api.jquery.com/).